# EJB3 persistence with a field that's not an entity

Tags: java, jpa

I've got the following situation

```
@Entity
public class myEntity implements Serializable {

    private AnotherClass anotherClass;
}


public class AnotherClass implements Serializable {

   private String ...
   private String ...


}
```

but `AnotherClass` IS NOT annotated with `@Entity`. I can successfully deploy my bean but when I try to persist a `MyEntity` class instance, it gives me `NoSerializableException`.

Is this because `AnotherClass` is not annotated with `@Entity`?

Answer (score 4):

Essentially, yes, although there's something else going on here.

Since `AnotherClass` is neither `@Entity` or `@Embeddable`, JPA may try to serialize it as a binary field instead.  It seems to be trying this, but the `NotSerializableException` suggests that some other field of either `MyEntity` or `AnotherClass` *isn't* serializable, causing the exception.

You almost certainly don't want `AnotherClass` persisted as a binary, so you need to annotate it to tell JPA how to persist it.